# Is it possible to craft a Python dict with all (or most) of the properties of a dict with Abstract Base Classes?

Tags: python, dictionary, abc

I am familiar with the concept of Abstract Base Classes (ABC's), as providing sets of properties of the builtin objects, but I don't have really any experience working with them. I can see that there's a `Mapping` ABC, and a MutableMapping that inherits from it, but I don't see a `.fromkeys()` method (the only thing missing off the top of my head.)

Would I be able to craft a dict with purely ABC's? What would that look like? Would that amount to nearly the same thing as subclassing `dict`? Would there be any benefit to doing that? What would be the use-case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would I be able to craft a dict with purely ABC's?

No. Subclassing an ABC requires *you* to implement its interface; for example, `Mapping` requires you to implement `__getitem__`, `__iter__`, and `__len__`. The mixin methods provide default implementations for certain things in terms of the parts you need to implement, but you still need to provide the core. `Mapping` won't automatically provide a hash table or BST implementation for you.

Comment: OK, so should I change my question to reflect that, and how to make that work? Or ask a new question?

Comment: Here's my follow-on question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361106/how-would-i-implement-a-dict-with-abstract-base-classes-in-python